# cannot restart the css animation onclick in chrome

Tags: javascript, css

I have search on the topic about restarting animation and that can be done by remove and add class again. But when I test it myself with the same method, I found that it doesn't work in many browsers. It only work in Edge. Is there something I did wrong?

here is the html:

```js
function(elem) {
  elem.classList.remove("animation");
  setTimeout(function(){
    elem.classList.add("animation");       
    elem.style.animationName = "transformOuter";
    elem.style.webkitAnimationName = "transformOuter";},1)
}
```

```css
div.wrapperL {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 38px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid white;  
  margin: 0 1px 5px 0;
}

div.wrapperLeft {
  width: 40px;
  height: 38px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey; 
}

div.animation {    
  -webkit-animation-name: none;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-name: none;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes transformOuter {
  0% {background-color: #FFFFFF; width: 40px; height: 38px; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 10;}
  40% {width: 120px; height: 114px; left: -40px; top: -38px;  font-size: 30px;} 
  60% {width: 120px; height: 114px; left: -40px; top: -38px; font-size: 30px; transform: rotateY(0deg);  }
  100% {width: 0px; height: 0px; left: 20px; top: 19px; background-color: #FFFFFF; transform: rotateY(360deg); z-index: 0; font-size: 0px;}
}
```

```html
<div class = "wrapperL">
  <div class= "wrapperLeft" onclick = functionAnime(this)></div>
</div>
```

I also have another keyframe without `-webkit-` but same thing inside.The animation do trigger once in chrome but when I click again, nothings happen.

Comment: There is error in you javascript your function is `functionAnime(this)` but you have called `function function` in javascript change that to `function functionAnime`and try if didnt workout then add some working fiddle with proper explanation of you scenario

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove style as well same as you did with class see working example:  And yes your function name was incorrect I assumed it was a typo.

```js
function functionAnime(elem) {  
  elem.classList.remove("animation");
  elem.style = '';
  setTimeout(function(){
    elem.classList.add("animation");                
    elem.style.animationName = "transformOuter";
    elem.style.webkitAnimationName = "transformOuter";
  },100)
}
```

```css
div.wrapperL{
float: left ;
width: 40px;
height: 38px;
background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
position: relative;
border: 1px solid white;  
margin: 0 1px 5px 0;}

div.wrapperLeft{

width: 40px;
height: 38px;
background: white;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid lightgrey; }

div.animation{    
-webkit-animation-name: none;
-webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
animation-name: none;
animation-duration: 5s;
animation-iteration-count: 1;}

@-webkit-keyframes transformOuter{
0%      { background-color: #FFFFFF; width: 40px; height: 38px; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 10;}
40%     {  width: 120px; height: 114px; left: -40px; top: -38px;  font-size: 30px;} 
60%     {  width: 120px; height: 114px; left: -40px; top: -38px; font-size: 30px; transform: rotateY(0deg);  }
100%    { width: 0px; height: 0px; left: 20px; top: 19px; background-color: #FFFFFF; transform: rotateY(360deg); z-index: 0; font-size: 0px;}}
```

```html
<div class = "wrapperL">
  <div class= "wrapperLeft animation" onclick = functionAnime(this)></div>
</div>
```